# change CAMetalLayer background color

Tags: objective-c, swift, colors, background, metal

My `CAMetalLayer` background color is black, even if i'm assigning new color as the `backgroundColor` property.

Am i missing something? Thanks!

Link to the original project :

https://github.com/audiokit/MetalParticles

Comment: can you add your code to have better understanding what's going on

Comment: If you're doing any rendering, you also need to set a clear color on the primary color attachment of your render pass descriptor. Something like: `renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = MTLClearColorMake(1, 1, 1, 1); renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = MTLLoadActionClear;`

Comment: hey @warrenm ! As far as i can see, it uses Computing and not Rendering. I'm pretty much lost at the code. I've attached the original project for your convenience!

Comment: @AdnanAftab Updated the project

Comment: @warrenm Updated the project

Comment: @RoiMulia are you talking about are ParticleLab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This project takes a rather unconventional approach to clearing the drawable's texture each frame: it replaces the textures contents with an array of zeros that is the same size as the texture (width * height * 4). Subsequently, it encodes some compute work that actually draws the particles. This is almost certainly not the most efficient way to achieve this effect, but if you want to make the smallest change that could possibly work (as opposed to experimenting with making the code as efficient as possible), Just fill the `blankBitmapRawData` array with your desired clear color (near line 82 of ParticleLab.swift).

Comment: Hey warrenm. You are always such a patience & awesome mentor! I'm trying to understand how could i achieve this, blankBitmapRawData expects [UInt8]. I tried assign it [1,1,1,1](RGBA). But it dosen't work. Can you direct me how to present clear/white color for the blankBitmapRawData?

Comment: Since the components are `UInt8`s, you need to specify each in the range of 0-255, not 0.0-1.0.

Comment: I've tried both [255,255,255,255] and [255,255,255] and the results are : http://prntscr.com/bk6fq4 .. ah :\ are we missing something?

Comment: Can you update the question with exactly how you're writing those values into the array? To be clear, you need width * height copies of those values in the array in order for the entire texture to be filled with your chosen color. It seemed to work for me when I just set the `repeatedValue` parameter to 255 (i.e. the background became white rather than black).

Comment: works! I'll be honest with you - I feel like Metal is above my level. I'm having a hard time understanding copied code lol. Tho i'm thinking about re-creating this all particle system, because you said it it's not the right & more efficient way creating it. Can you please direct me, or send some resource which could lead me to this particle systems? (the right way)

Comment: I think it's a fine approach overall. My comment about inefficiency was directed at the fact that using `replaceRegion` to copy pixel data into a texture might not be the optimal way to clear the texture each frame.

Comment: Cool. If there is a better method in overall(i'm always trying to optimize as far as possible). Can you direct me on what to search?

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through your code and can not see a place where you are setting background Color.

The metal layer is added as a sublayer to it, so you have to set it explicitly.

Add this line at the end of your init method in `ParticialLab` class and see if it works.

```
self.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
```

Comment: Still black.. as warrenm suggested, it might have to do with the sublayers being render/computed, but i can't understand where exactly should i place the renderPassDescriptor. (see his comment on the question above)

Comment: He is suggesting that create a renderPassDescriptor and set color attachments and after that create a MTLRenderCommandEncoder by passing renderPassDescriptor in

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/Render-Ctx/Render-Ctx.html

Answer (score 0):

I found that `self.isOpaque = false` was needed on the layer.